# Replace relative URLs with absolute URLS PHP

Tags: php, url, preg-replace, preg-match

I have an HTML document. I need to replace the url relative to absolute.

BaseUrl : `https://www.example.com/example/`

For example

```
/*different types of relative URL that I want to replace with absolute URL*/
<img src="/relative/url/img.jpg" />
<img src="./relative/url/img.jpg" />
<img src="../relative/url/img.jpg" />
<a src="../../relative/url/img.jpg" /></a>
<a href='relative/url/'>example</a>

/*url i don't want them to change*/
<img src="//example.com/img.jpg" />
<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg" />
<img src="https://example.com/img.jpg" />
```

Desired Output would be:

```
<img src="https://www.example.com/example/relative/url/img.jpg" />
<img src="https://www.example.com/example/relative/url/img.jpg" />
<img src="https://www.example.com/example/relative/url/img.jpg" />
<a src="https://www.example.com/example/relative/url/img.jpg" /></a>
<a href='https://www.example.com/example/relative/url/'>example</a>
```

But I have to account for single and double quoted attribute values for src, href, and action

Right now I am trying like this preg_replace:

```
preg_replace('~(?:src|action|href)=[\'"]\K../(?!/)[^\'"]*~',"$baseUrl$0",$html);
```

But it only works with some URLs. What I want is for them to work with all the relative URLs that I mentioned earlier.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Rather than showing us `relative/url`, can you instead show us the actual data you are trying to find, along with the actual replacement?

Comment: `'~(?:src|action|href)=[\'"]...`: no, extract the urls first using DOMXPath, and once done, apply the transformation.